# ImageAlign keeps breaking down

Tags: image-processing, debugging

I have posted the same question on the community (http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1394441?p_p_auth=YV2a4wzw).

I tried to register the movie posted below (compressed version here) using Mathematica but to no use. However I could manage to do the same very easily with another software (FIJI: https://fiji.sc/ ) with a plugin "StackReg" (http://bradbusse.net/sciencedownloads.html)

Input Video:

http://community.wolfram.com//c/portal/getImageAttachment?filename=ezgif.com-optimize.gif&userId=942204

The strategy that I used for the registration was as follows with both softwares:

1. Inverting (ColorNegate) the image
2. Applying a Gaussian Blur of radius 10
3. Thresholding the image to obtain a mask for the object
4. Registering the binarized image (mask) and saving the transformation matrices
5. Using the transformation matrices to obtain a registered version of the image.

for results obtained from FIJI/StackReg please see: http://community.wolfram.com//c/portal/getImageAttachment?filename=brightfield.gif&userId=942204

The code for Mathematica breaks when I do the same:

[image]

Can anyone please help me figure out why ImageAlign is breaking down?

This is a simple problem and I expect that the ImageAlign function should not break down on such a petty case. I checked my masks and they seem to be fine. I gave the masks that I generated from Mathematica to FIJI/StackReg which can successfully align them and yield the transformation matrices in a .txt file. This brings me to the second question, is there a way to get the transformation matrix (alignment matrix) from ImageAlign. Because I need the transformation matrices after alignment in order to align the original movie.

Note: StackReg aligns all the images relative to the first frame.

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about `ImageAlign` but thought it'd be fun to imitate what StackReg did in the video in your link.

Here's strategy based on the fact that the central blob will remain approximately circular throughout. Note that I use a bizzarro way to get the initial blob form--this isn't really necessary but is instead a byproduct of thinking that was where a bug in the code was (it wasn't).

The idea here is that we'll replace the blob with a rectangle, compute the rectangle corner points, then recenter and rotate based on this.

So first the image prep code so that we can find the true blob:

```
rawimg =
  Import["http://community.wolfram.com//c/portal/getImageAttachment?filename=ezgif.com-optimize.gif&userId=942204"];

gray = ColorConvert[#, "Grayscale"] & /@ rawimg;

boxImgPreprocess1[img_] :=
  DeleteSmallComponents[
   Binarize@
    Dilation[ImageClip[GradientFilter[img, .05], {.5, .8}, {1, 1}], 2],
   20
   ];
boxImgPreprocess2[img_] :=
 DeleteSmallComponents@
  Closing[
   ColorNegate@img,
   25
   ]
```

We can see here what that does:

```
Manipulate[
 .5*boxImgPreprocess2@boxImgPreprocess1[gray[[i]]] + gray[[i]] // 
  ImageResize[#, 350] &,
 {i, 1, Length@gray, 1}
 ]
```

[image]

Then I turn this into an array like so:

```
boxMeUp[img_] :=
 ImageData@boxImgPreprocess2@boxImgPreprocess1[img]
```

Then we compute the corner points of the bounding box of this. I had two ideas for how to do it, either the loopy way or the Mathematica way:

```
boxCorners1[boxArray_?MatrixQ] :=
 Module[
  {
   boxDim = Dimensions[boxArray],
   xrange, xpos,
   xmin = None, xmax = None,
   ymin = None, ymax = None
   },
  xrange = Range[boxDim[[2]]];
  xpos = {0, boxDim[[1]] + 1};
  Do[
   xpos = Pick[xrange, boxArray[[i]], 1];
   If[Length@xpos > 0,
    If[xmin =!= None,
     {xmin, xmax} = MinMax[{{xmin, xmax}, MinMax[xpos]}],
     {xmin, xmax} = MinMax[xpos]
     ];
    If[ymin == None, ymin = i],
    If[ymin =!= None, ymax = i - 1; Break[]]
    ],
   {i, Length@boxArray}
   ];
  {{xmin, boxDim[[2]] - ymin}, {xmax, boxDim[[2]] - ymax}}
  ]

boxCorners2[boxArray_?MatrixQ] :=

 CoordinateBounds@Position[boxArray, 1]
```

The former is about an order of magnitude faster than the latter, but they're both pretty fast:

b1 = boxMeUp[gray[[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJZjE.png)]];
b2 = boxMeUp[gray[[11]]];

```
boxCorners1 /@ {b1, b2} // RepeatedTiming

{0.0041, {{{166, 339}, {295, 210}}, {{152, 324}, {282, 194}}}}

boxCorners2 /@ {b1, b2} // RepeatedTiming

{0.040, {{{173, 302}, {166, 295}}, {{188, 318}, {152, 282}}}}
```

Note that `boxCorners2` would require some tweaking to work quite right

Now we'll check how this worked:

HighlightImage[gray[[125]], 
  Mean /@ Transpose@boxCorners1@boxMeUp@gray[[125]]] // 
 ImageResize[#, 350] &

[image]

```
HighlightImage[gray[[125]], boxCorners1@boxMeUp@gray[[125]]] // 
 ImageResize[#, 350] &
```

[image]

And it appears to have done fine

Now we turn these corner points into a rotation angle and translation vector suitable for `ImageForwardTransformation`:

```
boxAlign[c1_, c2_] :=
 Module[
  {
   midPoints,
   areas,
   translation,
   angle
   },
  midPoints = Map[Mean]@*Transpose /@ {c1, c2};
  areas = Times @@ Subtract @@ Reverse@# & /@ {c2, c1};
  translation = Subtract @@ midPoints;
  angle = ArcSin[-1. + Max@{Divide @@ areas, 1}];
  {angle, translation, midPoints[[1]]}
  ]
boxTransform[{angle_, translation_, center_}, dim_] :=
 Evaluate[
    Composition[
      RotationTransform[angle, center/dim],
      TranslationTransform[translation/dim]
      ]@{#1, #2}
    ] & /. {# :> #[[1]], #2 :> #[[2]]}
```

The trick here is that I assumed the blob would be of constant area, so that if it rotates by `θ` the ration of the areas will be transformed like `1 + Sin[2 θ]` or so. This actually turns out not to matter all that much, but it's nice for matching the video you had. It also only holds like 50% of the time, as usually the blob changes area just via some kind of breathing motion. Would work better for a rigid body.

Finally we stitch this all together into a `boxImageAlign` function and compute some data for the main reference image:

```
b1 = boxMeUp[gray[[1]]];
imDim = ImageDimensions[gray[[1]]];
bc1 = boxCorners1@b1;
boxImageAlign[n_Integer?(0 <= # <= Length@gray &)] :=

  ImageForwardTransformation[
   gray[[n]],
   boxTransform[boxAlign[bc1, boxCorners1@boxMeUp@gray[[n]]], imDim]
   ];
boxImageAlign[n_Integer?(0 <= # <= Length@gray &), 
   m_Integer?(0 <= # <= Length@gray &)] :=

  ImageForwardTransformation[
   gray[[n]],
   boxTransform[
    boxAlign[boxCorners1@boxMeUp@gray[[m]], 
     boxCorners1@boxMeUp@gray[[n]]], imDim]
   ];
boxImageCheckAlignment[n_] :=
  With[{b1 = boxImageAlign[n], m = 1},
   If[ImageQ@b1,
    {
      {
       ImageResize[gray[[m]]*gray[[n]], Scaled[.5]], 
       ImageResize[gray[[m]] + .5*Image@boxMeUp@gray[[n]], 
        Scaled[.5]]
       },
      {
       ImageResize[gray[[m]]*b1, Scaled[.5]], 
       ImageResize[gray[[m]] + .5*Image@boxMeUp@b1, Scaled[.5]]
       }
      } // ImageAssemble,
    $Failed
    ]
   ];
boxImageCheckAlignment[n_, m_] :=
 With[{b1 = boxImageAlign[n, m]},
  If[ImageQ@b1,
   {
     {
      ImageResize[gray[[m]]*gray[[n]], Scaled[.5]], 
      ImageResize[gray[[m]] + .5*gray[[n]], Scaled[.5]]
      },
     {
      ImageResize[gray[[m]]*b1, Scaled[.5]], 
      ImageResize[gray[[m]] + .5*Image@boxMeUp@b1, Scaled[.5]]
      }
     } // ImageAssemble,
   $Failed
   ]
  ]
```

Then we check one of the images with maximum misalignment:

```
boxImageCheckAlignment[75]
```

[image]

And the blobs match much better

If you turn off the rotation it honestly barely changes anything...

Finally here's an animation (not the smoothest, but turning off rotation might help):

[image: animation]

Comment: upvoting it. i will have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

**Why is `ImageAlign` breaking?**

The message gives an at least partly helpful hint about why `ImageAlign` is failing here. The source of the failure is that `ImageAlign` is first using `ImageCorrespondingPoints` to find a list of points, and then doing something similar to `FindGeometricTransform` to figure out what behavior describes the transformation.

This message that means that in at least one case, your masks stored in `binarized` share only one keypoint with the first mask you are aligning to. These keypoints are found by the default (SURF) method. Since that is not enough to establish a transformation, the function is informing you that it cannot proceed rather than using a transformation that may well be nonsense.

When we get down to brass tacks, we can find one such case where we lack corresponding points:

```
images = (ColorNegate@*ImageAdjust) /@ Import["http://community.wolfram.com//c/portal/getImageAttachment?filename=ezgif.com-optimize.gif&userId=942204"];

binarized = Binarize@DeleteSmallComponents[FillingTransform@Binarize[GaussianFilter[#, 10], 0.48]] & /@ images;
```

See:

```
ImageCorrespondingPoints[binarized[[1]], binarized[[12]], TransformationClass -> "Rigid"]
```

returns:

```
{{{304.516, 334.914}}, {{288.808, 198.547}}}
```

The way to get around this would be to use another keypoint method that does find enough pairs to find a good transformation.

**Potential workarounds:**

If you insist on using a keypoint method, you could try:

```
aligned = ImageAlign[First@binarized, Rest[binarized], Background -> 0, TransformationClass -> "Rigid", Method -> {"Keypoints", "KAZE"}];
```

I would look at `ref/ImageKeypoints` to find a method I liked. Some of these more detailed keypoint finders can be more computationally expensive.

Since the binarization is destroying a lot of keypoints, and it doesn't look like you have a good marker for rotation of the cell, you may as well just use a translation to align the centroids:

```
imDim = ImageDimensions[images[[1]]];
centroids = 1 /. ComponentMeasurements[#, "Centroid"] & /@ binarized;
translations = TranslationTransform[(# - centroids[[1]])/imDim] & /@ centroids;
centroidAligned = MapThread[ImageTransformation, {images, translations}];
ListAnimate[centroidAligned]
```

Comment: I tried. it does not work well

Comment: What do you mean by it not working well? What are your criteria?
Does it issue messages?
Have you tried other Keypoints methods besides KAZE? That was just an example of one method that found enough points.

Comment: The method you proposed does not issue any messages. And yes I have tried all methods available besides KAZE. My criteria is simple: the binarized masks should be registered and that the transformation should then be used over the original images for registration. Please see the video I posted on the community.